# My Array and Int keep resetting values when their method runs

Tags: java

I'm currently doing an assignment which requires me to use classes to make an album collection manager. I've been debugging and came across a problem. The Album[] is supposed to hold all the Album objects while numAlbums is supposed to keep track of the number of albums, but when I run the add method, it will increment the numAlbums and add the album to Album[], but once the method ends, it will reset instead of staying where it should be.

This is a problem especially since I can't print the album list since it relies on the numAlbums incrementing in value.

```java
public class Collection {
    private Album[] albums;
    private int numAlbums; //number of albums currently in the collection
    
    
    //find the album index, or return NOT_FOUND
    private int find(Album album) 
    {
        String title = album.getTitle(); // First, put the title and artist in string variables.
        String artist = album.getArtist();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < albums.length; i++) // Let's find this album.
        {
            Album c = new Album(); // Make Album c so we can compare every album.
            c = albums[i];
            
            if (title == c.getTitle() && artist == c.getArtist())  // If the title and artist match, then return the index.
            {
                return i; // We found the album!
            }
        }
        return -1; // Album doesn't exist.
    }
    
    //increase the capacity of the array list by 4
    private void grow() 
    {
        Album[] temp = new Album[getAlbums() + 4]; // Create new temp array with 4 more spaces.
            
        for (int i = 0; i < albums.length; i++) // Use loop to insert all values from albums to temp.
        {
            temp[i] = albums[i];
        }
            
        albums = temp; // Overwrite previous albums with new one.
    }
    
    // Add an Album. Command A.
    public boolean add(Album album) 
    {
        int counter = 1;
        
        if (getAlbums() == 0) // If there are no albums, grow the list to the first 4 indexes.
        {
            Album[] temp = new Album[numAlbums + 4];
            albums = temp;
        }
        else if (getAlbums() > 0)
        {
            Album search = new Album();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < albums.length; i++) // Check if the album has the same title and artist in the collection.
            {
                search = albums[i];
                if (album.getTitle().equals(search.getTitle()) && album.getArtist().equals(search.getArtist()) == true)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        
        int a = getAlbums();
        albums[a] = album; // Put the album in the collection.
        a++; // Increase the amount of albums.
        setAlbums(a);
        
        if (numAlbums == 4 * counter) // If the number of albums reach multiples of 4, then increase the array and counter.
        {
            grow();
            counter++;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < albums.length; i++) 
        {               
             System.out.println(albums[i]); // Simple print of the list.         
        }  
        
        return true;
    }
    
    // Remove an Album. Command D.
    public boolean remove(Album album) 
    {
        if (find(album) == -1) // First, find the album to remove.
        {
            return false; // That album does not exist.
        }
        else // The album exists.
        {
            int index = find(album); // Copy the index number.
            
            for (int i = index; i < albums.length; i++)
            {
                albums[i] = albums[i + 1]; // Shift the elements to the left by 1.
            }
        }
        
        int a = getAlbums();
        a--; // Decrease the amount of albums.
        setAlbums(a);
        
        
        return true; // We removed it.
    }
    
    //set to not available. Command L.
    public boolean lendingOut(Album album) 
    {
        if (find(album) == -1) // First, find the album to lend.
        {
            return false; // That album does not exist.
        }
        else // The album exists.
        {
            if (album.isAvailable() == false)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                album.setAvailable(false);
            }
        }
        return true; // We removed it.
    }
    
    //set to available. Command R.
    public boolean returnAlbum(Album album) 
    {
        if (find(album) == -1) // First, find the album to lend.
        {
            return false; // That album does not exist.
        }
        else // The album exists.
        {
            if (album.isAvailable() == true)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                album.setAvailable(true);
            }
        }
        return true; // We removed it.
    }
    
    //display the list without specifying the order. Command P.
    public void print() 
    {
        int y = getAlbums();
        if (y == 0) // If the collection is empty, then return empty.
        {
            System.out.println("The collection is empty!");
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < albums.length; i++) 
        {               
             System.out.println(albums[i]); // Simple print of the list.         
        }   
    }
    
    //display the list sorted by the release date. Command PD.
    public void printByReleaseDate() 
    {
        if (getAlbums() == 0) // If the collection is empty, then return empty.
        {
            System.out.println("The collection is empty!");
            return;
        }
        
        Album[] SortAlbumsRelease = new Album[numAlbums]; // Make another array to store the album list order.
        
        for (int i = 0; i < albums.length; i++) 
        {               
             SortAlbumsRelease[i] = albums[i]; // Copy the contents of the array.        
        }   
         
        Album First = new Album(); // Create temp albums so we can compare.
        Album Second = new Album();
        Album temp = new Album();
         
        for (int o = 0; o < albums.length; o++) // Go through every single album.
        {               
            for (int p = 0 + 1; p < albums.length; p++) 
            {
                First = SortAlbumsRelease[o];
                Second = SortAlbumsRelease[p];
                 
                int compare = First.getReleaseDate().compareTo(Second.getReleaseDate()); // Use the compare method from date to get a value.
                 
                if (compare == -1) // If the first value is lower, then put that album in the previous slot.
                {
                    temp = SortAlbumsRelease[o];  
                    SortAlbumsRelease[o] = SortAlbumsRelease[p];  
                    SortAlbumsRelease[p] = temp;  
                }
            }
        }
         
        for (int i = 0; i < albums.length; i++) // Print the list.
        {               
             System.out.println(SortAlbumsRelease[i]);         
        }
    }
    
    //display the list sorted by the genres. Command PG.
    public void printByGenre() 
    {
        if (getAlbums() == 0) // If the collection is empty, then return empty.
        {
            System.out.println("The collection is empty!");
            return;
        }
        
        Genre type = null; // Set the genre type.
        
        Album Temp = new Album(); // Make a temp album.
        
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) // Iterate through all the genre cases.
        {
            switch(i) 
            {
            case 0:
                type = Genre.Classical;
            case 1:
                type = Genre.Country;
            case 2:
                type = Genre.Jazz;
            case 3:
                type = Genre.Pop;
            case 4:
                type = Genre.Unknown;
            }
            
            for (int j = 0; j < albums.length; j++) // Look through the albums that have the matching genre.
            {
                Temp = albums[j];  
                if (Temp.getGenre() == type) // If they match, print in that order.
                {
                    System.out.println(albums[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public int getAlbums() 
    {
        return numAlbums;
    }
    public void setAlbums(int m) 
    {
        numAlbums = m;
    }
}
```

Below is the manager we have to create when running the program. We also use an album, genre, and date class, but I feel like the problem is somewhere in these areas.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CollectionManager 
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Collection Manager starts running."); // Begin.
        
        while(true)
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
            String collect = input.nextLine(); // Take the input in.
            
            String[] output = collect.split(","); // Creates an array "output" and splits the input by commas.
            
            // Below is the designated spots for array "output" after the split.
            // A,Change,Anika,pop,7/23/2021
            //[0] [1]   [2]   [3]   [4]
            switch(output[0]) 
            {
            case "A": // Add the album.
                Album a = new Album();
                if (a.MakeAlbum(output) == true) // If the output goes well and returns true, then add to the collection.
                {
                    Collection add = new Collection();
                    if (add.add(a) == true) // If true, add the album.
                    {
                        System.out.println(a + " >> added.");
                        break;
                    }
                    else // Otherwise, it's already in there.
                    {
                        System.out.println(a + "is already in the collection.");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else // If the date is invalid, then return Invalid Date!
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Date!"); 
                    break;
                }
            case "D": // Delete an Album.
                Album d = new Album();
                d.MakeAlbum(output);
                
                Collection delete = new Collection();
                if (delete.remove(d) == true) // If the album is in the collection, delete.
                {
                    System.out.println(d.getTitle() + "::" + d.getArtist() + " >> deleted.");
                    break;
                }
                else // Otherwise, it doesn't exist.
                {
                    System.out.println(d.getTitle() + "::" + d.getArtist() + " >> is not in the collection.");
                    break;
                }        
            case "L": // Lend an Album.
                Album l = new Album();
                l.MakeAlbum(output);
                
                Collection lend = new Collection();
                if (lend.lendingOut(l) == true) // If the album is in the collection, lend.
                {
                    System.out.println(l.getTitle() + "::" + l.getArtist() + " >> lending out and set to not available.");
                    break;
                }
                else // Otherwise, it doesn't exist or can't be lend out.
                {
                    System.out.println(l.getTitle() + "::" + l.getArtist() + " >> is not available.");
                    break;
                }
            case "R": // Return the album.
                Album r = new Album();
                r.MakeAlbum(output);
                
                Collection ret = new Collection();
                if (ret.returnAlbum(r) == true) // If the album is in the collection, return.
                {
                    System.out.println(r.getTitle() + "::" + r.getArtist() + " >> returning and set to available.");
                    break;
                }
                else // Otherwise, it doesn't exist or can't be returned.
                {
                    System.out.println(r.getTitle() + "::" + r.getArtist() + " return cannot be completed.");
                    break;
                }
            case "P": // Print with no order.
                Collection Print = new Collection();
                Print.print(); // Print the album list.
                break;    
            case "PD": // Print with release date order.
                Collection PrintD = new Collection();
                PrintD.printByReleaseDate();; // Print the album list by release date.
                break;    
            case "PG": // Print with genre order.
                Collection PrintG = new Collection();
                PrintG.printByGenre(); // Print the album list by genre.
                break;    
            case "Q": // Quit the program.
                System.out.println("Collection Manager terminated.");
                return; // The end.
            default: // Invalid. Try again.
                System.out.println("Invalid command!");
                break;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

I can't find anything on google relating to the problem so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You constantly create new instances of your Collection class with `new Collection()` and then work on those newly created objects. You should only create your collection object once and do all your work on that single object.

Comment: `if (title == c.getTitle() ...)` - check out [How do I compare Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: THANK YOU! You saved me from a big headache. Now I have a better understanding of how instances work.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable and method names are written in camelCase, and class names in PascalCase. So, for example, `MakeAlbum` should be `makeAlbum`, and `SortAlbumsRelease` should be `sortAlbumsRelease`. Further enum constants are written in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE, so `Genre.Jazz` should be `Genre.JAZZ` (I'm assuming here that `Genre` is an enum type).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're creating a new collection object per switch statement. Instead, create the object prior to your while loop.

```
//initialize collection object prior to while loop
Collection myCollection = new Collection();
while(true){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String collect = input.nextLine();
        String[] output = collect.split(",");
        switch(output[0]){
        case "A": 
            Album a = new Album();
            if(a.MakeAlbum(output) == true)
            {
                //adding to the same collection object created previously
                if (myCollection.add(a) == true)
                {
                    System.out.println(a + " >> added.");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(a + "is already in the collection.");
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Date!"); 
                break;
            }
        case "D":
            Album d = new Album();
            d.MakeAlbum(output);
            //removing from same collection object created previously
            if (myCollection.remove(d) == true)
            {
                System.out.println(d.getTitle() + "::" + d.getArtist() + " >> deleted.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(d.getTitle() + "::" + d.getArtist() + " >> is not in the collection.");
                break;
            }
 
      }

}
```

Should be all that takes to make your program work, now you're always just adding and subtracting from a single Collection object. Before, you were creating a new collection object per switch, and these objects couldn't be accessed at the end of the while loop.

Do this for the rest of your switch statements! I've only done the first two here. Let me know if it runs!